# Java static scoping

Tags: java

I have the following piece of code that is taken from a mock exam for Sun Certified Java Programmer:

```
public class Static
{ 
      static 
      { 
            int x = 5; 
      }

      static int x,y; 
      public static void main(String args[]) 
      { 
            x--; myMethod(); 
            System.out.println(x + y + ++x); 
      }

      public static void myMethod() 
      { 
             y = x++ + ++x; 
      }
}
```

The test asks you for the result of this line:

```
System.out.println(x + y + ++x);
```

The answer is 3, but I don't completely understand why it is 3. I can arrive at that answer if I completely ignore:

```
      static 
      { 
            int x = 5; 
      }
```

My question is, what is the meaning of the above code snippet? Why does it not change the value of the variable 'x'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's a *static initialization block*. but that doesn't really matter in this context since it's modifying the value of a variable local to it.

Comment: @anonymous, thanks I get it. It is scoped, so the variable doesn't exist after the scope.

Answer (score 5):

`int x = 5;` does get executed, but `x` here is a local variable, not the `static int x` member.

Answer (score 1):

it is a static block so the variables you define there cant go beyond the scope of the `{` and the `}`. works -in that sense- the same way as methods

Answer (score 1):

It changes the value of the local variable called `x`, but not the static member field called `x` i.e. it is just 0.

Answer (score 0):

x's value is set to 5, but only within the context of the static block

```
static 
      { 
            int x = 5; 
      }
```

The variable x declared in `static int x,y;` has class-level scope, and is affected by the rest of the code that references it.